# ReactJS - Front-end form error handler/validation

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, error-handling

I'm building a simple donation app in ReactJS.  Here is a working version here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-grzdgz

I've never done form error validation though. So if someone doesn't fill out a field, I'd like an error message to pop up, which says something like "this field must be completed".

I've been trying to follow this tutorial:
https://learnetto.com/blog/how-to-do-simple-form-validation-in-reactjs

But I'm kinda getting lost, about how I can pass these functions/error messages, into my form, which sits in a seperate module.  In the demo, everything sits in one file.

But in my app, my form sits seperately to index.js.  So I link to it in index.js.

I'm almost there, I just need some help connecting everything up.

Can anyone help me get form error validation working?

The error handling functions all sit here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-grzdgz

The form itself sits here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-grzdgz?file=components%2FForm.js

And some form errror heres:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-grzdgz?file=components%2FFormErrors.js

Any help would be great!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the submit, I would have a method called: `validateFields`, which would validate all field like you want (instead of using the default validator of html, which doesn't work on some browser). In the method, I would save all the field with an error.

If the error list (or object) is not empty, you use an alert or popup [react-popup](https://react-popup.netlify.com/)

If there are no error, you can call submit method.

Basically, it would look something like:

```
export default class DumbComponent extends React.Component {

  state = {} // all your field value

  validateField = () => {
    let error = []
    //Validate all your field

    if (error.length === 0) {
      this.submit()
    } else {
      this.showError() // You decide the way
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Form>
        <FieldOne />
        <Field2 />

        <SubmitButton onSubmit={this.validateField} />
      </Form>
    )
  }
}
```

Hope it answer your question!

Comment: Hi @alexandre rivest - thanks for the post. I don’t think this works with the way I’ve currently built my app though? Eg what is <field one/2>? And even though submit is in my form.js. Can I still use <submit etc> on my app.js. Are you able to make this work in my code?

Comment: <FieldOne /> can be a radio button, a text input, anything really. Unfortunately, I don't have much time to go in your code and fix it. Rapidly, i would say that you can do the validation in the props `handleSubmit` of your component form